# running rsync with quoted arguments using python's subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

I've got some automation backup script that executing `rsync` using `subprocess` module.
It was all fine until the new requirement to specify ssh identity file.

According to `rsync` manuals, ssh identity should be passed as quoted string:

```
-e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity"
```

But this will fail to run in `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-avz', '-e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity"', '~/Downloads', 'root@remote_server:/lvm/archive/backup'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fd111939710>
rsync: Failed to exec ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.0]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-avz', '-e', 'ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity', '~/Downloads', 'root@remove_server:/lvm/archive/backup'])`

Comment: Thanks :) So easy ... But why actually the reason that quotes not needed to be passed to `subprocess` ?

Comment: This is how the entire command line `rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity" ~/Downloads root@remove_server:/lvm/archive/backup` is parsed by shell and passed to `exec()` system call. I just parsed that manually. :-)

Comment: `shlex.split('rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity" ~/Downloads root@remove_server:/lvm/archive/backup')` =>
['rsync',
 '-avz',
 '-e',
 'ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/identity',
 '~/Downloads',
 'root@remove_server:/lvm/archive/backup']